# How can I redirect mobile devices to a different URL?

Tags: javascript, browser, mobile

I want to check whether the user is viewing my site from a mobile device or PC. If it's a mobile device, I want to redirect my site URL like Google does...

If possible I would like to implement this in JavaScript. How can I do this?

Comment: asked and answered by the `OP`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142273/standard-way-to-detect-mobile-browsers-in-a-web-application-based-on-the-http-r).

You will have better luck doing this server side, as many mobile browsers don't even support JavaScript. Basically you want to check the user agent and compare to a list of known mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You typically use the User-Agent header to detect the browser.

Here's JavaScript code that does basically that (only for mainstream browsers though, you'd have to add the Mobile User-Agents)

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

And here's a list of mobile browser identifiers

http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html

The list is not complete and will never be, given the rate new mobiles appear on the market, but what I did back when I did it is to store all received user agents in a database, and then look for them to classify them as mobile and which brand/model.

What you can't rely on though is JavaScript, it's better done in server code (not all mobile browsers execute JavaScript).

There is a related question here on SO but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple answer for this query. This won't detect the mobile browser, but it redirects the page to our `mobile.html` page, through the following script;

Find out the browser window size and redirect it..

```
winWidth=document.all?document.body.clientwidth:window.innderwidth;
if (winwidth<800)
{
 window.location.replace("mobile.html");
}
```