# Identify a cell phone by user-agent

Tags: php, mobile, user-agent, mobile-browser

Is there a good way to identify a cell phone or any other mobile device (which may be subject to a limited data plan) through the user agent or similar, easily accessible methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/), the Wireless Universal Resource File: *"The WURFL is an XML configuration file which contains information about capabilities and features of many mobile devices."*

Comment: I used the information from this file to generate a series of stripos() and preg_match() calls.

Comment: @KAwa it was before August 2011 but now [it wouldn't be](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/wmlprogramming/message/34311) :(

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to look in the User Agent for specific browsers and keywords like 'Mobile', 'Skyfire', etc. That should be a pretty reliable way. You'd want to do a Google Search for Mobile Browser UserAgents. Someone probably has made a list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot be certain of the exact phone used in many cases because many phones share the same user-agent string (and even use the same browser). BUt you can certainly narrow the possible candidates enough as to serve tailored content.

Check these related questions as well

- [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)
- [How can I redirect mobile devices to a different URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277226/find-mobile-browsers)
- [Standard way to detect mobile browsers in a web application based on the http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142273/standard-way-to-detect-mobile-browsers-in-a-web-application-based-on-the-http-r)

Comment: Not looking to identify the phone, just whether or not it is a phone.

Comment: I misinterpreted your "identify a cell phone" sentence then. Still you have to check for all the possible UAs, you cannot do it reliably in a single check (unless you build a monster regex)

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone UA signature is:

```
/Apple.*Mobile.*Safari/
```