# How to redirect URL to mobile version?

Tags: xhtml, mobile-website

I want to redirect some URL to mobile version, if the user agent is a mobile.

Example :

klikkarir.com/jawa-pos/5215/lowongan-call-center-accounting-administration-pt-asia-teleservices-januari-2010.html

will redirect to :

m.klikkarir.com/5215/lowongan-call-center-accounting-administration-pt-asia-teleservices-januari-2010/

somebody help me.

Comment: 15 questions, none accepted...

Answer (score 2):

I use [http://detectmobilebrowser.com](http://detectmobilebrowser.com/), and found it is the quickest and easiest way.  It works quite well.  This site generates server scripts automatically (php, perl, python, coldfusion, apache, jquery, etc.) that detects mobile browser and redirects accordingly.  You can just copy and paste the code somewhere in your Index file.

Comment: When trying the expression for IIS recommended in detectmobilebrowser.com website get error "expression too complex". And it is true is overly complicated. Prefer to use something like the suggested in here https://gist.github.com/dalethedeveloper/1503252

Answer (score 1):

The best method is to use [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) to detect if a mobile device is hitting your page, several (php,java,c++) interfaces exist.

If you want to have simpeler but less accurate solution a quick useragent comparison might be sufficient, [example](http://www.russellbeattie.com/blog/mobile-browser-detection-in-php).

Comment: what i need is redirect for specific URL, not redirect all to mobile version (if user agent is mobile)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Mobify Me](http://mobify.me/) service, there is a free version too.

**Off topic**, Start accepting answers

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are three ways to go about this first detecting the screen size by number of pixels. I have tried this method and It works within parameters (HD and high resolution screens on mobile devices vs older low resolution desktop screens) another approach suggestion several places (http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/how-to/mobile-redirect) is to use the .htaccess file. The idea here is to screen browsers on their acceptance of mobile MIME types - as I suspect there is no great push for full screen devices to take mobile MIME types this seems fairly reliable with the caveat that on tablet devices you may get the mobile version when they are capable of handling the main version. The third of course is to use the script solutions noted above. 
Luck
DPR