# how to detect a mobile phone in a web application

Tags: asp.net, mobile

If a web application, how can you figure out the visitor is viewing from a mobile phone?

is it also possible figure out the make/model like blackberry versus iphone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check their [User-Agent](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html) string.

Comment: will a user-agent be populated have those specific 'Device Information' as requested in the question ?

Answer (score 4):

Scott Hanselman [did a podcast](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=172) on a module device database that Microsoft [made available on Codeplex](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/).  It's a .browser file that you put in your ASP.NET (version 2.0+) website, which then helps the framework define the [`Request.Browser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser.aspx) property more closely.  You should be able to get a lot of the information that you need from there.

However, that project is **no longer supported**, and when you're dealing with user agent detection, having an up-to-date resource is very important.  You should probably use a similar project, such as [51degrees.mobi](http://51degrees.mobi/) or [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/).

Even without that, at the least you can check [`Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.ismobiledevice.aspx).

Comment: MDBF is now very old. For example; it does not contain tablets, or 4G/LTE devices. You could try 51Degrees.mobi from NuGet (http://nuget.org/packages?q=51degrees). It's a one click install with zero configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the User-Agent string. In JavaScript, that's really easy, it's just a property of the navigator object.

```
var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
```

You can check if the device if iPhone or Blackberry in JS with something like

```
var isIphone = !!agent.match(/iPhone/i),
    isBlackberry = !!agent.match(/blackberry/i);
```

if isIphone is true you are accessing the site from an Iphone, if isBlackBerry  you are accessing the site from a Blackberry.

You can use "UserAgent Switcher" plugin for firefox to test that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `httpRequest.Browser.IsMobileDevice`  in `Session_Start`

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Redirect mobile users to the mobile home page
    HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    if (httpRequest.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
    {
        string path = httpRequest.Url.PathAndQuery;
        bool isOnMobilePage = path.StartsWith("/Mobile/", 
                               StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (!isOnMobilePage)
        {
            string redirectTo = "~/Mobile/";

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectTo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, check this out. Worked fine for me!

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: A litte bit more information would have been nice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for User Agent.

Like... http://www.developershome.com/wap/detection/detection.asp?page=userAgentHeader

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information from a similar question:

[Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

It involves reading the user-agent header. The answers to that other question include links for scripts for this.

Here is another helpful discussion:

[Standard way to detect mobile browsers in a web application based on the http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142273/standard-way-to-detect-mobile-browsers-in-a-web-application-based-on-the-http-req)

Answer (score 0):

As preciously stated - user agent

**BUT**, do you really mean to ask "is it a mobile phone"? Or do you really mean something else?

Lines are blurring these days. I bought a nice little Android slate with 7" screen from eBay for $99. Is that a mobile phone?  Is a mini-netbook with 6" screen? Is a Kidnle-like-device?

I'm just wondering why you want to know if it is a mobile 'phone ... screen size? processing power? something else?

You probably did mean mobile 'phone but, if not, please rephrase and we can help further.