# How to recognize whether a web site is opened in a mobile or a PC

Tags: php, mobile, mobile-phones, mobile-website, device-detection

We have a site developed in PHP. It is working just fine. We have used JQuery for every kind of situation like slide shows, menus, etc.

This site contains a lot of images which are large in size. because of this when viewed in a mobile phone user has to scroll a lot.

How can we recognize whether the client (browser) trying to access our site is a mobile phone or a standard PC.

Is there any standard way to build site for such situations?

TIA

Comment: Before asking, please search.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142273/standard-way-to-detect-mobile-browsers-in-a-web-application-based-on-the-http-req.  This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at [Tera-WURFL](http://www.tera-wurfl.com), it is a PHP & MySQL-based software package that detects mobile devices and their capabilities.  Here is the Tera-WURFL code that you would use to detect if a request is coming from a mobile device:

```
<?php
require_once("TeraWurfl.php");
$wurflObj = new TeraWurfl();
$wurflObj->GetDeviceCapabilitiesFromAgent();
if($wurflObj->capabilities['product_info']['is_wireless_device']){
    echo "This is a mobile device";
}else{
    echo "This is a desktop browser";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this lib pointer.
It did the trick in the way I wanted it to do.

Comment: is it only this signle script? because when I tried to find something, I just came across of some packs of PHP files...

Answer (score 5):

you should check the user-agent header which is sent along the HTTP request. Since there are so many useragents, it's really difficult to recognize the various devices/platforms. For this purpose there is a freeware library which can help out : [wurfl](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)

Basically it maps the user-agent to a device object which you can query for it's capabilities. This way in your layout you can take advantage of the device's screenwidth/height, what image formats it supports, etc

Answer (score 1):

http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/mobile-device-recognition/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check it out and get back if required.

Answer (score 1):

We sometimes use Apache rewrite rules when a client wants to divert traffic before it reaches our server.

See http://www.bemoko.com//training.team/help/team/pc-to-mobile-redirect for more information.