# Determine which browser is being used to visit my site

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me how I can determine (using JavaScript etc.) what browser is being used to visit my site?

I want to redirect to a different page based on these scenarios:

- Wheater the user is browsing using Safari on the iPhone.
- Using IE on a desktop
- Using IE on a WP7 mobile device.

Thanks.

Comment: You could do this in JavaScript but that won't really help you much, as you will need to store that information somewhere to get it. What server side language/s can you use?

Comment: Server side language is PHP - all I need to do is ensure I present the mobile version to users browsing on a mobile device.

Comment: include that information in your post next time.  Also, add the PHP tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632165/detecting-mobile-browsers-on-the-web

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the Javascript Navigator object:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

```
alert(navigator.userAgent);
```

This script may help you for more complicated detection:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

You should be handling these redirections server-side though.  This is particularly true if you have a mobile version of your site.  Most mobile browsers *do* support Javascript just fine, but there are quirks.

Server-side, you can send a redirect by sending the 302 status code, and the `location:` header.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

**Edit:**  Since you say that you need to detect mobile browsers now in your comments, just use this script:  http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

Comment: Not working now. I tested with Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Chrome, they all showed "Netscape"

Comment: @Quan Check out `navigator.userAgent`.

Comment: I went to this link on Chrome http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_nav_all , and the result was "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36"