# Check if a device can print

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bit of an odd question, and I'm perfectly willing to accept that this just isn't possible, but is there a way of using jQuery or just normal JavaScript to check if a device is capable of printing?

We currently have a button on our article pages that allow the user to click in order to print the page. However on some Android devices the "javascript:window.print();" function just doesn't work.

I was just wondering if there was a way of performing a check to seeing if the device supports this?

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268840/determine-whether-browser-supports-printing

Comment: Probably not going to happen.  Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216551/detect-if-user-has-printing-capabilities

Comment: I doubt it. Plus, how would cloud printing be handled?

Comment: maybe you want read about this https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/overview

Comment: Thanks guys, apologies for the duplicate question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use feature detection for this:

```
if('print' in window){
  window.print();
} else {
  alert("Printing is not supported on this device");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Javascript has no way to know if the device can print. After all, this mostly depends on it being connected to a printer. But you could check if the function `window.print` is defined like this

```
if(typeof window.print == 'function') {
    //at least the function is available
}
```