# Detecting mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am finishing a mobile version for my site wich i am coding using JQueryMobile, so i have to make the redirection fo the mobile site but since there are a lot of old phones which do not support JQuery Mobile i wanted to do another version for mobile just using css and html. Is there any way to detect old phones and smartphones and to redirect to different url?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Standard way to detect mobile browsers in a web application based on the http request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142273/standard-way-to-detect-mobile-browsers-in-a-web-application-based-on-the-http-re)

Comment: Do you use any server side languages? I have an example in asp.net that redirects if that's of any use.

Comment: There are so man duplicated question of this! did you even look on the box of duplicated suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a third party application such as 51 Degrees mobile detection framework which is [listed on CodePlex](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/). There's plenty of documentation on the site to use when implementing it in your solution.